# Elements appear on the left side of the screen in constraint layout

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to set up the elements of my recycler view but they appear on the left side of the screen instead of in the middle. I would like them to appear on the middle instead, how can I manage that?

This is the items xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_margin="8dp"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tv_title"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textColor="@android:color/white"
       android:background="@android:color/black"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:textSize="18sp"
       android:padding="6dp"
       android:minLines="3"
       android:ellipsize="end"
       tools:text="Black Widow"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/iv_poster"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/iv_poster"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/iv_poster"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:scaleType="fitXY"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_title"
       tools:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the recycler view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/rvMovies"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this on item's ConstraintLayout:

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

Comment: I did it but even though it changes on my computer's screen, when I run the app it's still on the left. Any ideas?

Comment: What if you enclose item's ConstraintLayout on a LinearLayout and use gravity there and also android:layout_width = match parent?

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that out!